# Is there any way to calculate Daily Consumption using time offset?

Tags: timescaledb

I want to calculate daily usage from the cumulative values that I am recieving but the starting point of the day is from 8:00am . I am recieving points at every 5 min interval but I want to calculate daily usage from 8:00am of the previous day to 8:00am of the present day. It should take the closest point in the vicinity 8:00am to calculate the daily consumption. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by reducing 8 hours from your original date and grouping it via query:
`time - interval '8 hours'`.

Let's say I have a table named conditions, and I'd like to get a daily average temperature, from 8 am to 8 am of the next day, I can reduce 8 hours from the `time` column in a daily bucket and it should work as expected.

Example:

```sql
select time_bucket('1 day', time - interval '8 hours'), avg(temperature) from conditions group by 1 limit 100;
```